# Stored procedure taking more time than expected - SQL

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures

I was asked a question in Microsoft SQL Interview.

We have a Stored Procedure and it was taking 10 min to run. Recently we added a column in the Table and now it is taking an Hour. What would be the problem.

I answered the statistics have not been updated but not sure it was a satisfactory answer.

Can some of you share your experiences for this kind of scenario.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I wouldn't now how to answer this either. Only an additional column and the unaltered procedure suddenly takes six times as long to run? Maybe a full table scan that must read more sectors, because of a huge column? Hm, I don't know...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: That was an interview question. So you could ask whether the question referred to a particular DBMS or not.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: Hi Gordon, is this something you can answer?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of potential answers. I believe the important thing is to think about what adding a column can change.

Statistics is an important information for Optimizer to have the optimal plan. If the new column is used for predicate like `NewColumn = 'ColumnValue'` then statistics would help get the best cardinality estimate to aid Optimizer come up with the optimal plan but a predicate that's not supported by index isn't going to perform well. Plus, consider the impact of statistics if the query was `SELECT * FROM table` instead.  In this case, statistics on newly added column have no impact. In addition, the original question of "now it's taking an hour" implies it's a chronic issue.  This hints that the problem might be deeper than just statistics on the column (since statistics is created as soon as a column is used in predicate, if AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS option is on, which is the best practice)

Row size will change.  The page size is 8KB.  If the original table row size was fixed at 1.2KB, there would be 6 rows per page. But what would happen if the new column was say, `CHAR(4000)`?  The new row size is now at 5.2KB, and a page can hold only one row.  The number of page will be 6 times more than that of the original.  Will it take 6 times longer?  That I'm not sure, but I'm sure it'll take longer.

New uses for the new column by others could happen.  Is the new column used by others, and how often?  Consider a scenario of heavy INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operations by others on the new column, now lock contention/escalation or wait is a possibility.

Index is one of the last things I could come up with, though someone else is probably better qualified to explain that to you with a good example.  The impact of index, I *think*, depends on the query. Let's consider a drastic (bad) example of a query that's perfectly supported by an index with `WITH (INDEX(*index_name*))` option, and assume the index stayed the same and no additional index for the new column was made.  Using the new column in a predicate would be a sure way to slow it down.  Another is using a column that's not supported by index in `JOIN` clause.  And I'm sure there are many other ways.

The last thing in my mind is what the stored procedure is doing with the new column, which might be more of an necessary evil than a problem in design.  I'd expect an stored procedure that takes 10 min to be working with a nice size data.  While simply reading might not impact the time much, an example of sure ways to increase the time is to update the new column or other columns, perhaps based on the value of the new column, for a large number of rows.

I'm sure there are other reasons for slow down.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your feedback and investing time on this.
I found answer for this one.

It can be due to many reasons and some of them are as per below:

1. Statistics might not have been updated
2. If the Indexes have been created/modified for the underlying table used in the Stored Procedure.

Answer (score -1):

Use the OPTION (RECOMPILE) in your stored proc.
Check out this link for reference:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mdegre/2011/11/06/what-is-parameter-sniffing/

Comment: How do you know Babu is using SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, Its SQL Server.